# Derivative of a valuation map for a second order ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $V:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ a smooth potential. Given $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\psi_{\lambda}$ be the solution to
$$-\psi_{\lambda}''+\lambda V\psi_{\lambda}=0$$
with initial condition $\psi_{\lambda}(0)=0$, $\psi'_{\lambda}(0)=1$.

Let us fix $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, and consider the map
$$\mathcal{G_x}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\quad\mathcal{G_x}(\lambda):=\psi'_{\lambda}(x)$$
It is easy to show that $\mathcal{G}_x$ is of class $\mathcal{C}^1$.

**I would like to find an explicit expression for $\partial_\lambda G_x$ (in term of $x,V$ and $\psi_{\lambda}$), at least at the point $\lambda$ such that $\psi'_{\lambda}(x)=0$.**

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: The usual procedure is to just differentiate the ODE wrt $\lambda$, so $y=\partial \psi/\partial\lambda$ solves $-y'' +\lambda V y =-V\psi$, $y(0)=y'(0)=0$. This gives $y(x,\lambda)$ in terms of the solutions of the original problem, by using variation of constants for this (inhomogeneous) equation. (Standard ODE theory guarantees that this formal procedure gives the correct answers.) You won't be able to get anything more explicit than this for general $V$.

Comment: PS: You wanted $y'(x,\lambda)$, but this can be obtained in the same way. In fact, a good first move might be to introduce $Y=(\psi,\psi')^t$ and rewrite the ODE as a first order system.